# Trying to insert "Custom Columns" into a SQL query Pull

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am pulling data from SQL Server using SSMS and/or DBeaver.  I am running a simple Select statement with specified Columns already written into the query and having no issue.  Now because I plan on joining this data with other tables, I want to create two columns called EventType and EventSubType.  EventType will simple = 'REVENUE' for all tables but the subtype will represent the table the data is being pulled from.

I have tried using the following and iterations of this as this was the direction I was told to take yet every time I am being told there is a syntax error by 'REVENUE'.  I'm also concerned because I thought Insert was mostly used to insert new columns or data into a table... I'm just trying to create these columns for the output of this query.  I hope that makes sense and please let me know if you need any additional information.  Thank you all in advance.

```
INSERT 'REVENUE' as EventType
'INVOICE' as EventSubType
SELECT
  EventType
  , EventSubType
  , invoiceno
  , ProviderBranchCode
  , ExternalClientID
  , episodeMinId
  , episodeMaxId
  , episodeMinStartDate
  , episodeMaxEndDate
  , serviceDateMin
  , serviceDateMax
  , serviceLines
  , invoicepostDate
  , invoiceServiceLine
FROM (table location)
```

Comment: OK i feel silly...  i was able to fix it with this...

SELECT EventType = 'REVENUE'
,EventSubType = 'INVOICE'
,invoiceno
,ProviderBranchCode
,ExternalClientID
,episodeMinId
,episodeMaxId
,episodeMinStartDate
,episodeMaxEndDate
,serviceDateMin
,serviceDateMax
From (TABLE)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with this:

```
SELECT
  EventType = 'REVENUE'
  , EventSubType = 'INVOICE'
  , invoiceno
  , ProviderBranchCode
  , ExternalClientID
  , episodeMinId
  , episodeMaxId
  , episodeMinStartDate
  , episodeMaxEndDate
  , serviceDateMin
  , serviceDateMax
FROM (TABLE)
```